# Python argparse with possibly empty string value

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I would like to use argparse to pass some values throughout my main function. When calling the python file, I would always like to include the flag for the argument, while either including or excluding its string argument. This is because some external code, where the python file is being called, becomes a lot simpler if this would be possible.

When adding the arguments by calling parser.add_argument, I've tried setting the default value to `default=None` and also setting it to `default=''`. I can't make this work on my own it seems..

```py
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--projects_to_build', default='')
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

This call works fine:

```
py .\python_file.py -p proj_1,proj_2,proj_3
```

This call does not:

```
py .\python_file.py -p

python_file.py: error: argument -p/--projects_to_build: expected one argument
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to pass a [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) value of `'?'` with `const=''`

```
parser.add_argument('-p', '--projects_to_build', nargs='?', const='')
```

You should also consider adding `required=True` so you don't have to pass `default=''` as well.

Comment: If you want more than 1 argument passed as a list, could be useful when you want to pass these args to a third party like pre-commit git hook, you can use:

`nargs='*', default = ''`