# SystemExit 2 error in the compilation of code when calling -e', '--episode', type=int, default=2000,

Tags: python

```
my code is a below:
if __name__ == '__main__':
  

      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

      parser.add_argument('-e', '--episode', type=int, default=2000,
                          help='number of episode to run')
      parser.add_argument('-b', '--batch_size', type=int, default=32,
                          help='batch size for experience replay')
      parser.add_argument('-i', '--initial_invest', type=int, default=20000,
                          help='initial investment amount')
      parser.add_argument('-m', '--mode', type=str, required=True,
                          help='either "train" or "test"')
      parser.add_argument('-w', '--weights', type=str, help='a trained model weights')
      args = parser.parse_args()
    
      maybe_make_dir('weights')
      maybe_make_dir('portfolio_val')
    
    Error:-
    usage:  [-h] [-e EPISODE] [-b BATCH_SIZE] [-i INITIAL_INVEST] -m MODE
            [-w WEIGHTS]
    : error: the following arguments are required: -m/--mode
    An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
    
    SystemExit: 2
```

So in the above error i am not able to understand what is the mistake i have also imported all the libraries correctly.

Comment: It just means you should run the program with `-m something` as you set `-m` argument as required.

Comment: @adamkwm can you please elaborate i am not able to understand what argument i haven't used any of those in e,b,i too above

Comment: How you run your program in command line? The error message separate in two parts, the first part tell you the correct usage, arguments in square brackets are optional while others are required. the second part tell you where the error occur, which is the missing `-m` argument.

Answer (score 0):

try changing this:

```
parser.add_argument('-m', '--mode', type=str, required=True,
                          help='either "train" or "test"')
```

to this: (notice `nargs` and `const`)

```
  parser.add_argument('-m', '--mode',nargs='?', const='' , type=str, required=True,
                      help='either "train" or "test"')
```

then you can add this to your code:

```
 if len(args.mode) == 0:
      print('-m either "train" or "test"')
      import sys
      sys.exit()  #closes python script
```

as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58396626/13093413